Replace a hyphen with a slash in an nginx rewrite
My HTML:
<a href='accueil/accueil.html'>

My nginx rule:
    location ~ \.html$ { 
        rewrite (?<module>([a-zA-Z]+))/(?<menu>([a-zA-Z]+))\.html$ /controleur?module=$module&menu=$menu last;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?root=$uri&$args;

    }

(?\<module\>(\[a-zA-Z\]+))**/**(?\<menu\>(\[a-zA-Z\]+)) doesn't work, but (?\<module\>(\[a-zA-Z\]+))**-**(?\<menu\>(\[a-zA-Z\]+)) yes (with href tag accueil-accueil.html).
Can someone help me?

have you tried escaping the slash \/ (like you escaped your dot \.)?

yes, and it doesn't rewrite the url
